# Clickable area of a link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a strange situation. I have a simple link with a really strange clickable area. I can click above and below the link, but when I put my mouse over the letters, I can not click the link. I tried to expand the clickable area, but it expands just outside of the text. So if the user clicks directly on the text of the link, nothing happens. I have some other links on the page, and they work fine. So you maybe know, what can be the problem?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
        <a href="web.html" id="webMore">Erfahren Sie mehr</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have following style for the link.

```
a {
   display: block;
   color: $mainOrange;
   position: relative;
   &:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: $hoverOrange;
   }
   &:visited {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: $mainOrange;
   }
   &:after {
       top: -10px; bottom: -10px;
       right: -10px; left: -10px;
   }
}
#webMore {
   position: relative;
   top: 25px;
   font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: i see nothing wrong http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPbwZv unless some involved CSS is missing.

Comment: Ok, do not know, what was the problem, but when I set my z-index to 9999, the problem got solved. Thx for your help guys!

Answer (score 3):

May Be your browser supports perfectly or not... you must try

-o- for opera

-moz- for Mozilla

-webkit- for other browsers , do like this >

```
<pre>

    a {
   display: block;
   color: $mainOrange;
   position: relative;
     -webkit-color: $mainOrange;
     -webkit-position: relative;


   &:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: $hoverOrange;
       -moz-text-decoration: none;
       -moz-color: $hoverOrange;
       -webkit-text-decoration: none;
       -webkit-color: $hoverOrange;
       -o-text-decoration: none;
       -o-color: $hoverOrange;
   }
   &:visited {
        -webkit-text-decoration: none;
       -webkit-color: $mainOrange;
       //same for -o-  & -moz-
   }
   &:after {
       top: -10px; bottom: -10px;
       right: -10px; left: -10px;
       //same for -o-  & -moz-
   }
}
#webMore {
   position: relative;
   top: 25px;
   font-size:25px;
}
//HTML CODE AS IT IS
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
        <a href="web.html" id="webMore">Erfahren Sie mehr</a>
    </div>
</div>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check other CSS **a** element style, because I've checked your code on blank page - it works fine.

If this is not CSS problem check your JS scripts or HTML.